# I'm unable to access Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network

I have created Azure Storage account, inside storage account created container and uploaded files to my container.

When I tried to access the Container from browser. Getting: **This request is not authorized to perform this operation**. ,Assigned **Storage blob Contributer** and also **Storage Blob Owner** but same issue.

Comment: can you share your blob url which you are trying access from browser?

Comment: No, I'm accessing from portal itself.Error is already shared in qns.

Comment: How did you create the container - programmatically or via Azure Portal? If the prior, then you might have used different credentials than the one you are in when trying to access from the portal. Question needs to have more details than provided.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to access the blob Storage. As I got below**

[image]

I created storage account with container, like below.

**Azure Portal > Storage accounts > Create a Storage Account**

> Note: If you want to access Azure Blob from public Internet, Select Enable public access from all networks under Networking section or if you select Enable public access from selected Virtual network and IP Address, it will access only particular Virtual Network.

[image]

**Container Creation: **

**Azure Storage Account > Containers > Container >**

[image]

Assigned **Storage Blob Data Contributor** to my storage account, Like below.

**Azure Storage Account > Select your Storage Account > Access Control (IAM)> Add > Add role Assignment > Storage Blob Data Contributor**.

[image]

**My blob is accessible over the Public Internet**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those files/container are private, this means only authorised users can access to them. To access a particular file with your browser, you need to grant permissions to that file. One of many solutions is to use SAS token (Shared Access Signature). In resume, this will generate a url with a token and this url can be pasted in a browser to access the file.

SAS token can be configured at some levels:

- User delegation
- Service
- Account

One of the benefits (it has a lot more) of SAS token is that you can define an expiration policy for that SAS token, so it not be externally accesible for eternity.

You should configure Share Access Policies if those files have sensible content or block some paths to protect them from external access.

Please, refer to the official documentation for more info about SAS Token usage:

[What is SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature)

[Grant limited access to Azure Storage resources using SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json)